# Time stamp array that loops and creates differences of values inside based on their index

Tags: python, numpy

Currently, I am working with the following;

```
timer = np.hstack(np.arange(100).reshape(100, 1))

def delta(timestamps):
   """Accrual periods"""
   for i in range(timestamps):
     dtimes_1 = timestamps[i] - timestamps[i - 1]
     dtimes_2 = timestamps[i + 1] - timestamps[i - 1]
   return(dtimes_1, dtimes_2)
```

What I am trying to achieve is a function which receives the timer vector as the timestamps input and will difference their values in two ways; 1. as Ti - Ti-1 and 2. as Ti+1 - Ti-1.

In the timer variable I have placed the numbers 100 and 1 but realistically, these numbers will be determined by user input effects on preceding functions and outputs (mostly on how many iterations and the length of time-steps).

In this particular example, if timer were to equal [0], [1], [2], [3], I would hope that dtimes_1 would return three values: [0], [1], [1] and that dtimes_2 would return [0], [2], [2], etc.

Comment: What is your question? Does the function not work correctly?

Comment: I receive the following error:
"TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're trying to do. Why is the expected output for `dtimes_1` has length 4 and not 3? If there are 4 elements, there are three deltas between them.

Comment: Apologies, that is a poor example. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: I still don't see where the zero comes from. Let's say `timer = [[1], [2], [4], [8]]`. From your formulas, I would expect `[[1], [2], [4]]` and `[[3], [6]]`.

Comment: Since you've made me consider this, I probably do need the output for a "Nothing" result to be [0] and in that sense, I would hope dterms_1 returned four results in your example; [[0], [1], [2], [4]] although I don't know how to apply this parameter either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `d1[i] == T[i+1] - T[i]` and `d2[i] == T[i+2] - T[i]` is enough, you can do this:

```
import numpy as np

def delta(timestamps):
    """Accrual periods"""   
    dtimes_1 = timestamps[1:] - timestamps[:-1]
    dtimes_2 = timestamps[2:] - timestamps[:-2]
    return dtimes_1, dtimes_2

timer = np.array([1, 2, 4, 8]).reshape(4, 1)
d1, d2 = delta(timer)

print(timer)
print(d1)
print(d2)
```

Output:

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [4]
 [8]]

[[1]
 [2]
 [4]]

[[3]
 [6]]
```

If you *really* want to have it with the exact arithmetic you asked for, consider this:

```
def delta(timestamps):
    """Accrual periods"""   
    dtimes_1 = np.vstack((None, timestamps[1:] - timestamps[:-1]))
    dtimes_2 = np.vstack((None, timestamps[2:] - timestamps[:-2], None))
    return dtimes_1, dtimes_2
```

Output:

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [4]
 [8]]

[[None]
 [1]
 [2]
 [4]]

[[None]
 [3]
 [6]
 [None]]
```

Here I used `None` as the fill value, but you can also use zero or something else.

Comment: Why not np.diff?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I didn't see a way to get the second diff easily, and I wanted both of them be implemented similarly. Maybe I'm missing something, so if you have a better solution, please do post.